# Parse twitter gem output in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, parsing, twitter

I'm using the Twitter gem to search a user's tweets with a specific hashtag. Now I want to parse the output and render it in the view but am not sure how. I have the following controller action working:

```
def profile_hustle
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  @profile_tweets = Twitter.search("#hashtag from:#{@profile.twitter}")
end
```

This gives me output like:

```
[#<Twitter::Status:0x007fbf331aec40 @attrs={"created_at"=>"Wed, 21 Dec 2011 04:18:39 +0000", "from_user"=>"username", "from_user_id"=>userid, "from_user_id_str"=>"userid", "from_user_name"=>"User Name", "geo"=>nil, "id"=>otherid, "id_str"=>"otherid", "iso_language_code"=>"fr", "metadata"=>{"result_type"=>"recent"}, "profile_image_url"=>"http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/user/Screen_shot_2009-09-23_at_11.39.35_PM_normal.jpg", "profile_image_url_https"=>"https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/user/Screen_shot_2009-09-23_at_11.39.35_PM_normal.jpg", "source"=>"&lt;a href=&quot;http://twitter.com/&quot;&gt;web&lt;/a&gt;", "text"=>"Test 2 #hashtag", "to_user"=>nil, "to_user_id"=>nil, "to_user_id_str"=>nil, "to_user_name"=>nil}>, #<Twitter::Status:0x007fbf331aebf0 @attrs={"created_at"=>"Wed, 21 Dec 2011 04:12:27 +0000", "from_user"=>"username", "from_user_id"=>userid, "from_user_id_str"=>"userid", "from_user_name"=>"User Name", "geo"=>nil, "id"=>149341436104544258, "id_str"=>"149341436104544258", "iso_language_code"=>"fr", "metadata"=>{"result_type"=>"recent"}, "profile_image_url"=>"http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/user/Screen_shot_2009-09-23_at_11.39.35_PM_normal.jpg", "profile_image_url_https"=>"https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/user/Screen_shot_2009-09-23_at_11.39.35_PM_normal.jpg", "source"=>"&lt;a href=&quot;http://twitter.com/&quot;&gt;web&lt;/a&gt;", "text"=>"Test #hashtag", "to_user"=>nil, "to_user_id"=>nil, "to_user_id_str"=>nil, "to_user_name"=>nil}>]
```

I want to render it in the view to show the text, and if possible <%= link_to %> the user's Twitter profile for each tweet. I did this with xml to javascript but am having trouble with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% @profile_tweets.each do |tweet| %>
  <%= link_to tweet.text, "http://twitter.com/#{tweet.from_user}" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hm, okay this is how I was doing it but it was crashing my rails server. So I'll focus on the server crashing. Thanks!